# Wordpress custom walker menu doesnt' display items

Tags: wordpress, navbar, menuitem

I'm working with the custom menu Walker class but have troubles on displaying menu items.
The only menu item which's displayed is the "home" item.
I created two pages but I just get void link tags.
Plus the "home" menu item doesn't get the "hvr-bounce-to-top" class and I would like all the items to get that class.

This is the result I get checking firebug:

```html
<div class="nav-menu">
    <ul>
        <li class="current_page_item">
           <a href="http://localhost/portfolio/">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-4" class=" hvr-bounce-to-top ">
           <a></a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-2" class=" hvr-bounce-to-top ">
           <a></a>
        </li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

This is the wp_nav_menu code in header.php:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 
                'theme_location' => 'primary', 
                'menu_class' => 'nav-menu', 
                'container' => false,
                'echo' => true,
                'before' => '',
                'after' => '',
                'link_before' => '',
                'link_after' => '',
                'depth' => 0,
                'walker' => new DescriptionWalker()                    
                ) );//wp_nav_menu
        ?>
```

And this is my Walker class in the function.php theme directory:

```
class DescriptionWalker extends Walker_Nav_Menu
{
  function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args)
  {
       global $wp_query;

      echo 'title = ' . $item->title;
      $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

      $class_names = $value = '';
      $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;

      $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item ) );

      $class_names = ' class=" '. esc_attr( $class_names ) . ' hvr-bounce-to-top "';

      $output .= $indent . '<li id="menu-item-'. $item->ID . '"' . $value . $class_names .'>';

      $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
      $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
      $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
      $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';


      $item_output = $args->before;

      $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';

      $item_output .= 
                        $args->link_before . 

                        apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID );


      $item_output .= $args->link_after; 
      $item_output .= '</a>';

      $item_output .= $args->after;

      $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
      }
}//DescriptionWalker
```

Thank you

Comment: I tried to echo $output and $item at the start of the method but seems like $output and $item are void.

Comment: Using a var_dump($item) I've found out that the object exists but it's like the tutorial I followed didn't explain wich type of object it is so using $item->title doesn't work but $item->post_title works.
Have to find out how to manage those objects with the Walker class